Should links to BRF (Braille) files include the 'dowload' attribute?
Should a hyperlink to a BRF (Braille) file include the download attribute?
<a href="blah.brf" download>blah.brf</a>
or
<a href="blah.brf">blah.brf</a>
I typically do not add 'download' unless the content of the file is something most users want to 'save for later' as opposed to 'do it now'
does the same apply to BRF files? Are there any BRF users who can comment?

As far as I know, there is no strict definitive guideline to tell you if a link is a normal or download link, but I would say that anything potentially not opened by the browser should be considered as a download.
Otherwise said, as soon as your link point to anything else than an HTML page, it's something to download.
Even if nowadays browsers can open a lot of non-HTML files (such as PDF, MP3, TXT, ...) you can't actually know if it will be effectively opened inside the browser, or launch another application. The user has normally a way to choose and/or tell when the default behavior isn't wanted. The good practice is to don't force anything, because it's very annoying when it doesn't behaves as you are used to / as you have configured your system.
You can't either guess reliably if the user is going to consume the content right now or save it for later, and shouldn't try to impose anything here either.
